# What does a high theta mean for an option position?

Tags: options, call-options, option-strategies, metric

I have a Call Spread for a position in `TSLA` that has a `theta` of 15.67 with 43 days left till expiration. I can see that it's comprised of a 64.71 and a -49.04 theta.

How can I best understand what it means?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option prices consist of two parts: the intrinsic value (the difference between the strike and the current price of the stock) and a time premium, representing the probability that the stock will end up above the strike for a call (or below for a put).

All else being equal, options decline in value as time passes, since there is less uncertainty about the expected value of the stock at expiration and thus the time premium is smaller.  Theta is the measure of the change in value in one day.  So for every day that passes, the calls you sold are going down in value by $64.71 (which means your theta is positive to you since you sold them at a higher value) and the calls you bought are going down in value by $49.04. So your position (a short spread) is gaining $15.67 each day (assuming no change in stock price or volatility).

On a per-share level, since you traded 10 contracts (totaling 1,000 shares), your *per-share* theta for each position is +6.47 cents and -4.904 cents, for a net theta per share of +1.576 cents per day.

Also, theta is not constant over time. It increases slowly until you get close to expiration, then increases more rapidly.

In reality, the stock price and volatility also change every day, and those are much stronger drivers of the value of your options.  In your case, however, the options are deep out of the money, meaning it's very likely that they'll expire worthless, so all you have left is time premium, which is decaying as time goes on.

Comment: So if the average premium I received for the position is $0.30, you're saying that the premium price is going down by $15.67 per DAY? (Assuming everything else holds equal)? How can that be if the premium was only $0.30?

Comment: @Shamoon That's the premium _per share_.  The Theta if for the _whole position_ One option contract is typically 100 shares.  How many contracts did you buy?

Comment: I bought 10 contracts, so that's $300 premium received. Every day, assuming all else is equal, that means I can buy it back for $15.67 less?

Comment: So dividing those by 1,000 (10 X 100), your theta per share is 6.471 cents on the buys and -4.904 cents on the sells, for a net decline of 1.567 cents per day. The change is also per _trading day_, not per _calendar day_; there are roughly 20 trading days until those option expire.

Comment: Theta is measured in cents or dollars? Because if it's 1,000 shares and the net theta is 15.67, that's $1.567 per day, not cents, right?

Comment: Theta is in dollars, but you have options on 1000 shares (each option contract is for 100 shares) so it's $15.67 / 1,000 = 1.567 cents per share.

Comment: Oh you _sold_ the spreads?  Then I have it backwards - you are _gaining_  $15.67 per day (I'll amend my answer)

Comment: This answer and the comments are  a bit FUBAR, so  I'm not sure how to sort it out and won't try  Some comments though.  (1) Delta  represents the probability that the option will end up ITM,  not time value.  (2) Theta is non linear so premium isn't going decreasing the same amount every day.  It accelerates as time passes.   (3) If this is a vertical spread, you can't  sell two calls, one going down $64.71 a day and the other down $49.04 per day.  Typo?  (4) Multiplying by 10 calls complicates things. Analyze the behavior of one unit.

Comment: @BobBaerker I fixed the typo and added the per-share information and addressed the non-linearity.

Comment: @D Stanley - Thanks.  It makes more sense now and a reader will get a better grasp of what's happening.